# ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template splash/splashpage, application/splashpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting this error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template splash/splashpage, application/splashpage with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}

Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/user/desktop/BudgetApp/app/views"
  * "C:/Users/user/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/turbo-rails-1.4.0/app/views"
  * "C:/Users/user/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actiontext-7.0.4.3/app/views"
  * "C:/Users/user/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/actionmailbox-7.0.4.3/app/views"
):

app/controllers/splash_controller.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in splashpage'
app/controllers/splash_controller.rb:3:in `splashpage'
```

below is the code

SplashController

```
class SplashController < ApplicationController
  def splashpage
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :splashpage }
      format.json { render json: { message: "Hello, world!" } }
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/splash/splashpage.html.erb

```
<h1>Splash#splashpage</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/splash/splashpage.html.erb</p>
```

Comment: This error cannot be reproduced and is not due to any issue with the code provided so it's very likely that its just human error on your part. Double check the file names and paths and that you have actually saved the view file. Also you don't need to explicitly `render :splashpage`. You can just do  `format.html` (with no block) and Rails will implicitly render the view with the same name as the action.